# Turn on TLS 1.2

Tags: ssl, authorize.net, tls1.2

I just received an email from Authorize.net informing that they deactivate connections to their server using TLS1.0 and TLS1.1.

Question are Godaddy SSL and Web Host set for TLS1.2 connections and is there anything need to change for configure TLS1.2 for my site?

How to check which TLS use in my website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to check which TLS use in my website?

Use Qualys SSL Labs vulnerability tester to check which TLS version you are using: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

You may certainly see that you support several versions (this is the most common case).

> Question are Godaddy SSL and Web Host set for TLS1.2 connections and is there anything need to change for configure TLS1.2 for my site?

You have nothing to do, web hosting services by GoDaddy are already supporting TLS 1.2 connections (and TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 - they do not support SSL v3 nor SSL v2 anymore, and it's a good thing).